# App crashing as soon as i click the button

Tags: java, android

As soon as I click the button student the app crashes. Here is the full code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Button buttonStartStudentActivity = findViewById(R.id.button_student);
        buttonStartStudentActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startStudentActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startStudentActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StudentStartingScreenActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

xml of the button:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_student"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:text="STUDENT"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
```

Error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.StudentStartingScreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Not sure how to fix this, hopefully someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Check your stacktrace in android studio while debugging ,it must be showing the exact error/cause

Comment: To open window press `Alt+6` while running the app

Comment: and than edit your question

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.StudentStartingScreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Gives this error

Comment: Does this make your code working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.StudentStartingScreenActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

As you say this is  the error means you `StudentStartingScreenActivity` dosen't exist.
Do this check the activity in your project or check it in `AndroidManifest.xml`  I think you've not defined the activity in the manifest.xml check it in it .
If not define it like this;

```
<activity
            android:name=".StudentStartingScreenActivity"
            android:theme="Yout theme name" />
```

Do check the name of your activity and it's presence in your project